# how to do splitFastq by file number instead of read num in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

`splitFastq` has a parameter `by`, only support read number.
I thought of firstly calculating the read num of fastq and then divide the desired file number to get this value. But I dont know how to pass it from a channel.

So my input channel ch_A is like: `[id, val(readnum), id.fq1, id.fq2], [id2, val(readnum), id2.fq1, id2.fq2],...`

how to pass readnum to the next splitFastq?

I tried `ch_A.splitFastq(by：{ tuple -> tuple[1]})` but I got error

Comment: I don't think that is possible with the current implementation of `splitFastq`. You could use groovy to read number of lines to calculate the number to break into *n* files, but it seems simpler to add a quick process using something like `seqkit`'s `split2` [function](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/#split2).